Как создать массив который будет содержать и цифры и строки
Есть такие классы для распарсинга json:
 public class Product
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int rating { get; set; }
    public string brand { get; set; }
     public int volume { get; set; }
    public List<Sizes> sizes { get; set; }

}
public class price
{
    public int total { get; set; }
}
public class Sizes
{
    public price price { get; set; }
}
public class Hz
{
    public int total { get; set; }
    public  List<Product> products { get; set; }
}
public class SiteResponce
{
    public int state { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }
    public int payloadVersion { get; set; }
    public Hz data { get; set; }
}

и есть такой метод, записывающий эти данные в csv файл:
 public void save_csv(List<SiteResponce> items)
 {
     using (var writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Profiles\\wb_data.csv", true))
     using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
     {
         foreach ( var product in items[0].data.products )
         {
             csv.WriteRecords(new[]
             {
                 product.id,
                 product.name,
                 product.sizes[0].price.total,
                 product.brand,
                 product.rating,
                 product.volume
             });
          }
      
      }
  }

Но мне выдает ошибку, что нет подходящего типа для неявно типизированного массива. Что делать?

Ну попробуйте new object[] { ... }, а вообще ошибку нужно приводить целиком как есть, а не в вашем пересказе.


ИМХО, CSV ужасный формат для хранения данных, он очень капризный, к тому же, у вас в проекте уже есть JSON, какой смысл перегона из формата в формат... Не знаю... 2. Вы делаете довольно странные вещи, ибо от вас просят коллекцию классов, а вы просто собрали свойства в один массив и пытаетесь что-то с ними  сделать. Ну посмотрите как минимум документацию, раздел Writing a CSV File, увидите там records = new List<Foo>, а теперь сравните с тем, что вы делаете...


спасибо сработало

Предлагаю использовать тип даных object и выводить все через цикл for
    object[] nume = new object[2];
    nume[0] = 1;
    nume[1] = “hello world”;
    for(bute i=0;i<nume.Length;i++)
    Console.WriteLine(nume[i]);
    

